# std::vectors in classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I'm building a c++ program, and I need to store an indefinite (i.e., dynamic) number of images within a class. I also have an indefinite number of sprite objects which can display those images.
Right now I have something like this:

```
class Hud {
  std::vector<Image> images;
  std::vector<Sprite> sprites;
}
```

In order to avoid duplication of the images (thereby taking up excessive ram), I re-use them by putting a pointer to the image in the Sprite object.

Obviously, when an Image is added to the std::vector, these pointers are no longer any good. There's probably something wrong with my approach, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Rendering is being done in OpenGL. Any suggestions would be helpful.

How can I store a dynamic array of images that can be accessed by my sprite objects, and that will allow me to avoid duplicate images in memory (which can be extremely taxing for particle effects)? Alternate methods would be welcome, but I can't afford to spend more than a day or two rewriting my code.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Obviously, when an Image is added to the std::vector, these pointers are no longer any good"* ... why would that be? And you aren't storing pointers in the above code ... you're storing copies of objects.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Because inserting into a vector can shift elements to the right of it around. And reallocation (exceeding the capacity) can cause all elements to be moved elsewhere.

Comment: @Nicol - which means he's passing around pointers to elements in the vector, not to the Images themselves. That's kind of what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @Brian Roach His `Sprite` objects have a `Image *` member pointing to an element in the Image vector. Those pointers can get invalidated if you inserts something in the Image vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be storing a list of `shared_ptr`, not a list of `Image` objects. That way, the list and `Sprite` classes can share ownership. Indeed, if you don't want the `Sprite` to actually own the image, they could store a `weak_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`. Though it's more likely that you would want the list itself to be a list of `weak_ptr`.

If you're not using a compiler with TR1 or C++11 support, then you can get these smart pointers from Boost.

Alternatively, you can use a `std::list`. That way, you can insert and remove from the list to your heart's content without invalidating pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can store pointers to the objects in your vectors, making sure to `delete` the objects before erasing them from the vector. Boost's shared pointer library might make this easier.